# Изменить права на файл во всех подпапках Linux

Tags: linux, chmod

Есть множество папок. В каждой есть файл example.php.
Права на этот файл в количестве 200+ шт -r--r--r--

Задача - изменить на всех файлах, рассованным по подпапкам установить права -rwxr-xr-x

Answer (score 3):

Стоя в нужной папке:

```
chmod 755 -R example.php
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже разобрался, именно так и сделал, уже новый вопрос публикую

Comment: @user3600595, будьте любезны поставить галочку, если ответ был полезен.

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk, не думаю, что он был полезен OP'у — ключ `-R` не работает, как описано в вопросе...